# Installing ruby using MacPorts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, macports

I'm installing Ruby using MacPorts. 
After using the following command:

```
sudo port install rb-rubygem
```

I got the following error:

```
Error: Port rb-rubygem not found
```

What should I be doing?

Comment: if MacPorts driving you to drink? Try Homebrew! http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ruby is installed by default in every mac. However, it's ruby 1.8, which is very old and shouldn't be used in any of your projects.

Take a look at [rvm](https://rvm.io/).
It will allow you to install several versions of ruby in the same system.

So, for example, you can do the following :

```
rvm use 1.9.3
ruby -v #=> ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16 revision 34643) [x86_64-darwin12.2.0]
rvm use 2.0.0
ruby -v #=> ruby 2.0.0p0 (2013-02-24 revision 39474) [x86_64-darwin12.2.1]
```

Using rvm, you can install any new version of ruby using the following :

```
rvm install 2.0.0-p0 #=> This will install Ruby 2.0.0
rvm install jruby #=> This will install jruby
```

And so on

Comment: I don't know what `rb-rubygem` is, but you don't need it.

Answer (score 5):

This post is old but I'll add this here. If you want to use mac ports you can add ruby by using `sudo port install ruby` and then `sudo port install rb-rubygems` (notice you missed the 's' in rubygem**s** in your original post). You can always check what repositories are available in mac ports by typing `port list`. Hope this helps.